# Why can't I inspect elements in cypress.io

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

Why can't I inspect elements in cypress.io window?

I have installed cypress 3.1.0 and when I run a test I can see it open in the chrome window. I run the same code at work and in my window at work, I can right click and Inspect Element, for some reason I can't do the same thing at home. Odd indeed.

In Cypress it says I am running Running Electron 59.I totally can inspect in a normal chrome window. My chrome version is browser Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit). Am I missing something here?

*** update, at work I found out I am using 3.0.2
*** update, I also notice at home, I get a 2nd icon in the window bar for cypress at home, at work I get a 2nd chrome window icon in the window bar

Answer (score 4):

Inspector is indeed hidden. `Ctrl + Shift + D` ( `Cmd + Shift + D`) will move its position to a visible area.

Comment: Wow, thank you! My devTools in cypress somehow disappeared and I couldn't figure out why for the past few weeks...

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue opening the inspector whether via shortcut or "click > Inspect" (Chrome 69, OSX 10.11.6, Cypress 3.1.0)

What is happening is that the dev tools are opened with a size of about 1x10 pixels on my top left corner, and I have to hide other windows in order to see the tools and be able to resize them.

Chances are that the Inspector is opened but hidden somewhere.

Hope that this helps

Comment: I will see if this helps, thanks for helping! If this answers it I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Right-click on an element in the cypress.io browser simulation & click Inspect no longer works. No longer displays the element details in console.